# C program, can't for the life of me figure it out

Tags: c

Ok so I have to increment a function into my code to get it to load a bunch of numbers that eventually will reach the sqrt of the number that is input my the user, all by using a while loop. The problem is, the number does not go into the function, and it loops indefinitely because the false is never reached. Any help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    double in, out, var, new_guess, old_guess;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%lf", &in);

    while(fabs(in - sqrt(old_guess)) >= 1e-5) {
        new_guess = (old_guess + (in / old_guess)) / 2.0;
        printf("%11.5lf", old_guess); 
    }
    printf("Estimated square root of %11.5lf: %11.5lf\n", in, new_guess);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is `<-` in `new_guess <- (old_guess + (in / old_guess)) / 2.0;`?

Comment: Never seen the `<-` operator in C before, but it seems that `old_guess` never changes between iterations, and that's what your loop condition is testing on?

Comment: What is the initial value of `old_guess` in `while(fabs(in - sqrt(old_guess)) >= 1e-5  )`? It is undefined behavior unless the compiler is zeroing it out. And Yes, the loop will never end of course.

Comment: Change `<-` --> `=`.

Comment: @Randolffchar Code does not know the value of `old_guess` on the first iteration in `while(fabs(in - sqrt(old_guess))`.

Comment: the <- was just included in the function I was given to increment, I've never seen it either which seems odd

Comment: `<-` is the `<` operator followed by the unary `-`.  Legal code, but functionally pointless here.

Comment: ok i had added, old_guess = in; before the loop, the loop now just cycles a bunch of the input number without putting it into any equations

Comment: Using `sqrt` and then trying to guess it seems pointless. Maybe you should check if `fabs(in - guess * guess) >= 1e-5`. Also in your code you are comparing `in` with square root of `guess`. That makes no sense

Comment: Also, *I have to increment a function* is not a correct statement wrt `C`. I think you mean a "variable".

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...). Improve your code to get no warnings. **Use the debugger** `gdb`. Spend several days or weeks reading more. StackOverflow is not a *fix-my-code* or *do-my-homework* service, so your question will be closed. Read also http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 0):

Once you get all your syntax issues resolved, you will still never get the desired result because the math in your predictor/corrector method will never converge. Specifically, `fabs(in - sqrt(old_guess))` will always be `>= 1e-5` as `in` will always be greater than the `sqrt` of `old_guess`.

Further, if you are using a predictor/corrector method to compute the square root of a number, it rather defeats the purpose to use `sqrt` in the iteration. If you were going to use the `sqrt` function to find the answer, you could simply do:

```
double answer = sqrt (in);   /* problem solved */
```

The purpose of an iterative method is to converge on a solution by using either a rate or average difference to repeatedly refine your guess until it satisfies some condition like a error tolerance between repeated terms (which it appears you are attempting to do here)

To iteratively find the square root of a number using the method you are attempting to use, you first find the next lower or higher *perfect square* of the number entered by the user. A simple brute force of starting at `1` and incrementing `x` until `x * x` is no longer less than `in` is fine.

You then divide the input by the *perfect square* to predict the answer, and then take the average of the input divided by the predicted answer plus the predicted answer to correct for error between the terms (and repeat until your error tolerance is reached)

**note** you should also include an iteration limit to prevent against an endless loop if your solution does not converge for some reason.

Putting it altogether, you could do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define ILIM 64     /* max iteration limit */
#define TOL 1e-5    /* tolerance */

int main(void)
{
    double in, n = 0, new_guess, old_guess, root = 1;

    printf ("Enter a number: ");
    if (scanf ("%lf", &in) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (root * root < in)    /* find next larger perfect square */
        root++;

    /* compute initial old/new_guess */
    old_guess = (in / root + root) / 2.0;
    new_guess = (in / old_guess + old_guess) / 2.0;

    /* compare old/new_guess, repeat until limit or tolerance met */
    while (n++ < ILIM && fabs (new_guess - old_guess) >= TOL) {
        old_guess = new_guess;
        new_guess = (in / old_guess + old_guess) / 2.0;
    }

    printf ("Estimated square root of %.5f: %.5f\n", in, new_guess);
    printf ("Actual : %.5f\n", sqrt (in));

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** `sqrt` is only used to provide a comparison with your iterative solution)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/sqrthelp
Enter a number: 9
Estimated square root of 9.00000: 3.00000
Actual : 3.00000

$ ./bin/sqrthelp
Enter a number: 9.6
Estimated square root of 9.60000: 3.09839
Actual : 3.09839

$ ./bin/sqrthelp
Enter a number: 10
Estimated square root of 10.00000: 3.16228
Actual : 3.16228

$ ./bin/sqrthelp
Enter a number: 24
Estimated square root of 24.00000: 4.89898
Actual : 4.89898

$ ./bin/sqrthelp
Enter a number: 25
Estimated square root of 25.00000: 5.00000
Actual : 5.00000

$ ./bin/sqrthelp
Enter a number: 30
Estimated square root of 30.00000: 5.47723
Actual : 5.47723
```